# C++ Add byte value to CString as int

Tags: c++, int, byte, arrays, cstring

Let's start off by stating that I have 0 xp with C++.

I have a byte array which is filled with data.

Example:

```
byte 0: 1
byte 1: 75
byte 2: 125
byte 3: 66
byte 4: 114
byte 5: 97
byte 6: 109
```

I have a CString in C++ which is supposed to get all the bytes. But bytes 0-2 are supposed to be int's and bytes 3-6 are supposed to be ASCII characters.

When I read the bytes and place them in the CString the following will be shown:

`" K}Bram"`

Only the "Bram" part is correct. 
The output should be:

```
"175125Bram"
```

I have a switch on the byte array's index so I can control the bytes.
For bytes 0-2 I use the following code:

```
receiveStr += "" + (int)buffer[i]);
```

For the bytes 3-6 I use the following code:

```
if ((buffer[i] >= 0x20 && buffer[i] <= 0x7E) || (buffer[i] == '\r') || (buffer[i] == '\n') || (buffer[i] == '\t'))
{
    receiveStr += buffer[i];
}
else
{
    // Display the invalid character placeholder (square)
    receiveStr += (char)0x7F;
}
```

How can I 'convert' the first bytes to int's?

Comment: Um? are you using `char`? not unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does it mean when you call 'convert to int'? How should it look like in the output?
Your first 3 bytes already stored as int values, but its representation is still ascii characters.

If it meant to be string like "175125Bram" then solution should be like this

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream ss;
ss << buffer[0] << buffer[1] << buffer[2];
receiveStr += ss.str();
```

Comment: receiveStr += ss.str(); is not possible
+= is something C++ is not agreeing with
ss.str() cannot be added to a CString

Comment: Then you may add all your bytes to ss just with << operator, then take ss.str().c_str()

Comment: That returns the string as: " K}Bram"

Comment: Try then
ss << (int)buffer[0] << (int)buffer[1] << (int)buffer[2];

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways.. Maybe `itoa`, a non-standard function, is the most well-known one. [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)/[swprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf) also can be solution. They require a fixed-size buffer, but maybe you can know appropriate size in this case.

In C++11, there is [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)/[std::to_wstring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) function. it converts numbers into `std::string`/`std::wstring`.